# Can a generator of the Multiplicative Cyclic Group of Integers mod n, where $n= 2p^k$ , be a composite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

In the Multiplicative Cyclic Group of Integers $\mod n$, where $n=2p^k$, $p$ is prime, it appears the generators are always prime numbers. However, I have not found any proofs of such nor any counter-example to prove otherwise.

So, when $n= 2p^k$, are the generators only prime numbers or can they be composite numbers as well?

I know composites can be generators when $n = p^k$, $p$ a prime.

Comment: That does it. Thanks, Dietrich. Grandparents from beautiful Austria.

Comment: There is a heuristic which can be used here to at least make it very implausible for only primes to be generators: We are not really working with the numbers but with their remainders mod $n$. Since this does not preserve being a prime, it would be a very happy coincidence if it still happened that restricting ourselves to the smallest positive representative should give a prime. Of course, this is only a heuristic, so looking for examples is good.

Comment: Sometimes you just can't see the forest for the trees. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Also for $n=2p^k$ composites can be generators. Take $n=2\cdot 5^2=50$. Then the group $U(50)$ has order $\phi(50)=20$, and indeed $a=33$ has order $20$, and hence is a generator, which is composite.